# Re-Ordering an Array to Match Specific Criteria

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I've been trying to figure out a way to sort the following array in a specific order but am stuck. I have the following Javascript array of employees:

```
var employees = [
        {employee_name: "Bob Taylor", position: "AG", date_hired: "2020-01-01 08:00:00"},
        {employee_name: "Amy Thomas", position: "AG/NG", date_hired: "2020-01-02 08:00:00"},
        {employee_name: "Robert Atkin", position: "NG", date_hired: "2020-01-01 08:00:00"},
        {employee_name: "Pam Holland", position: "NG/JF", date_hired: "2020-01-05 08:00:00"},
        {employee_name: "Suzy Roberts", position: "KF", date_hired: "2020-01-01 08:00:00"},
        {employee_name: "James Thornton", position: "KF/V", date_hired: "2020-01-07 08:00:00"},
        {employee_name: "Andrew Pebbles", position: "KF/V", date_hired: "2020-01-01 08:00:00"},
        {employee_name: "Lisa Acosta", position: "V", date_hired: "2020-01-02 08:00:00"}
];
```

I need to re-order the list of employees so that it matches the following order:

```
var positions = ["AG","NG","JF","KF","V","G","F","ANY"];
```

The "G" and "F" positions would be able to be filled by any employee whose position contains a "G" or "F" in it. The "ANY" position is a wildcard and can be filled by any employee.

Basically, as long as an employee's position from the employees array contains one of the strings from the positions array (with the exception of "ANY" which is a wildcard), he/she is eligible for that position.

In this particular instance, there's always going to be 8 employees in the array. Amy Thomas would be able to fulfill the "AG", "NG", "G", and "ANY" position requirements from the list. Pam Holland would be able to fulfill the "NG", "JF", "G", "F", and "ANY" position. James Thornton can fulfill the "KF", "V", "F", and "ANY" position, and Lisa Acosta can fulfill the "V" and "ANY" position.

So in the case of Pam Holland, she will have to be the third element in the array because she's the only employee on the list that fulfills the "JF" position.

I would like to figure out a function that re-orders the employees array until the criteria is met. However, this function would also need to make sure that it is sorted by earliest hire date to latest hire date to the extent that the position requirements are still met. I hope that this makes sense.

Please feel free to reply with any questions if my explanation is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Array.sort` method, providing a comparison function:

```
 function comparePosition(employee1, employee2) { 
  if (employee1 is 'inferior' to employee2)
     return -1;
  if (employee1 is 'superior' to employee2)
     return 1;
  // employee1 and employee2 are at the same level
  return 0;
 }

employees.sort(comparePosition)
```

Comment: of course, you can compare your hiring dates when the position is similar, I just provided the base principle of the comparison function for you.

Comment: sorry, I read through too quickly and didn't understand you wanted more than sorting from high to low position.